# How to fix "Failed to build the app . Error: unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am kinda new to gcloud and I don't know how to fix this error :(

When I try to deploy my API to Cloud run I get this error message:

```
Failed to build the app. Error: unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

this is the detailed logs:

```
[0m
[91mWARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[0m
unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to build the app. Error: unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

this is what I'm trying to import in the 1st file (snsr.py):

```
import requests
import numpy
import time
from time import sleep
import re
import random 
import math
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

this is what I'm trying to import in the 2nd file (main.py):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import snsr
import os 
import binascii
import hashlib
```

this is my requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==2.0.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
requests
numpy
regex
python-math
urllib3
os-win
```

this is my docker:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

Comment: Looks like the pip in your docker is outdated, try adding this command to your docker before installing the requirements 'RUN pip install -U  --upgrade pip'

Comment: The pip upgrade message is a warning and can be ignored. A `non-zero` return code is the problem and this is caused by `pip install -r requirements.txt` and, since your `Dockerfile` is straightforward, I think it's a consequence of one of your requirements.

Comment: A convenient diagnostic **if** you have `docker` or `podman` (or other) installed locally is to try and build the container locally (`docker build --tag=deleteme --file=./Dockerfile .` and see what errors arise. An advantage with containers is that, if it (doesn't) build in one place, it (shouldn't) build any place.

Comment: My guess (!) is that [`os-win`](https://pypi.org/project/os-win/) is the problem.

Comment: OpenStack and Cloud Run are different services. Cloud Run is not based upon Windows or Hyper-V. You have multiple problems. Start by building your container locally and running in a Linux environment. Remove Windows Hyper-V requirements. Configure gunicorn to listen on the correct Cloud Run port (default is 8080).

Comment: @DazWilkin It downloads all of the requirements as shown here: https://pastebin.com/cXhmeDZT

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the last error message. The gcc (c/c++ compiler) package is not installed.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm kinda lost right now. What should I fix then ?

Comment: Did you complete the items in my comment? Start there.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have fixed the error but when I visit the site it responds with 500 error

Comment: I have one file named snsr.py which I'm importing one function from to the main flask API file. It shows me a error in the snsr file on the first line where I'm importing this: `import requests
import numpy
import time
import re
import random 
import math
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import unquote
`

Comment: It all works when I run the application on localhost ... (I'm using port 5000)